# cabal install in cabal sandbox doesn't work when running from SSH

Tags: haskell, cabal

I have a cabal-sandboxed Haskell project on a server. If I do this on the server it installs in the sandbox:

```
 cd project && cabal install
 # installs in .cabal-sandbox/bin
```

But if I do this from my laptop, it installs into the global `~/.cabal/bin`

```
 ssh my@server "cd project && cabal install"
 # installs in $HOME/.cabal/bin
```

How can I get the sandboxing behavior to work with commands issued over SSH?

Comment: Which shell is SSH using?  Is the path different?  Is the SSH shell invoking an old Cabal-install binary that is unaware of cabal sandboxes?

Comment: ssh ... 'echo $SHELL' says /bin/bash

Comment: You're right! It's the PATH

Comment: But even using the right cabal doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: OK I think I figured it out. Thanks

Comment: If you solved you should add an answer to your questions. It could help someone in the future.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to fix the PATH in the ssh command:

```
ssh my@server 'export PATH=/home/me/.cabal/bin:$PATH && cd project && cabal install'
```